# kivy is not detecting touch input

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy, touch

I have installed kivy on my Ubuntu and connected a touch screen, but when I touch the screen kivy doesn't detect that.

To detect mouseclicks is no problem, just touch isn't working.

I already did the changes in config.ini:`

```
mouse = mouse; 
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev; hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

Thats my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
```

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class TouchInput(Widget):

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    print(touch)
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    print(touch)
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    print("RELEASED!",touch)
```

class SimpleKivy4(App):

```
def build(self):
    return TouchInput()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    SimpleKivy4().run()

Does anybody have a other idea why kivy doesn't detect my touch input?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged ros, this isn't a ros question. If you want to listen to a motion event, [you have to bind your callback to Window](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html), in the python; I'd test it out by print()'ing the events as you get them.

Comment: Did you mean `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

Comment: yes it meant that

Answer (score 0):

While you've defined your `on_touch_*(self, touch)` function, it's not enough to define it. The [Window](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.on_touch_down) module has a `on_touch_*` method, but it is currently bound to None. It is the Window module, not your own classes/widgets, that manages the whole window of your app, that calls the callbacks such as motion and touch. [Under the docs for input.motionevent](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html#listening-to-a-motion-event), it has the following on how to listen (use your callback) for a motion/touch event:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    # Receives a motion event with the [pos] profile
    pass
Window.bind(on_touch_down=on_touch_down)
```

You're missing the `Window.bind(window_method=my_function)` call.

Comment: Thank you I've added it, but kivy still only detect mouse clicks and not when I touch the display with my finger. The touch device is okay I proved it, only kivy don't get it.

Comment: Then you have to specify the input device; cf [Providers](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.providers.html) and [Config](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html#module-kivy.config) for Input.